# MySQL copy column from different tables, insert at top of table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm trying to merge a couple tables together to consolidate the data, but when I try to insert a column from one table to the other, the query I'm using inserts the records after the last currently existing record in the table. There are a ton of questions about duplicating columns, but they all seem to be starting with an empty table.

```
INSERT INTO newTable( newColumn ) SELECT oldColumn FROM oldTable
```

How do I modify this query to insert the rows at the beginning of the table instead of the end?

Visual representation of what is happening (left) vs. what I want to happen (right):

```
+--------+--------+------------+    +--------+--------+------------+
| ID     | Column |  newColumn |    | ID     | Column |  newColumn |
+--------+--------+------------+    +--------+--------+------------+
| 1      | 12345  |            |    | 1      | 12345  |    12345   |
| 2      | 12345  |            |    | 2      | 12345  |    12345   |
| 3      | 12345  |            |    | 3      | 12345  |    12345   |
| 4      |        |    12345   |    +--------+--------+------------+
| 5      |        |    12345   |
| 6      |        |    12345   |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the data in column 1 and 2?

Comment: The ID's are the same, if that would help. It is data exported from google analytics; right now, each metric has its own table, and I'm trying to put them all into one.

Comment: Yes that helps a great deal. You should update instead of insert and combine it with a join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need an UPDATE statement **not** an INSERT statement:

```
UPDATE newTable 
    JOIN oldTable
    ON newTable.id = oldTable.id
SET newcolumn = oldcolumn;
```

A tested example may be seen here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77724/1

Comment: That did it. Thanks! (Safe update mode needs to be turned off to do this.)

Comment: @bernie. Oke, you where first. I was bussy making a fiddle.